# How do I insert a hyperlink inside an f string in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently making a script with python and selenium to bulk send emails, I'm currently stuck trying to insert a hyperlink into the body of the email, because it looks better than just sendind the link, any help will be apreciated.
I'm using the f string inside de Send_keys command.

edit, here is my code so far (its in spanish, im sorry)

```
cuerpo.send_keys(f"""Hola {dataframe.loc[i]['Contacto']}
Mi nombre es Luis Contreras y soy KAM de xxxx. En xxxx somos expertos 
en el desarrollo de plataformas de software y en consultorías de innovación y 
transformación digital, nos caracterizamos por nuestro enfoque 
multidisciplinario y profesional, contando con más de 7 años de experiencia 
en el rubro.
Le escribimos dado que al evaluar detenidamente su sitio web 
{dataframe.loc[i]['web']} pudimos identificar las siguientes oportunidades de 
mejora:
-{dataframe.loc[i]['Observaciones']}
Como empresa creemos firmemente que, además de solucionar este tipo de 
problemas, podemos ser el partner tecnológico capaz de llevar su plataforma 
digital a su verdadero potencial. Si esta oportunidad es llamativa para ti y 
te interesa saber un poco más de nuestra empresa, podemos agendar una 
reunión. Si quieres me comunicas tu disponibilidad o eliges un horario 
directamente a través de {<a href="www.link i want.com">este enlace</a>}
Saludos. 
Luis Contreras.
KAM.
""")
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

which email service are you using ,

it is working properly just add the hyperlins as url instead of html tag

```
cuerpo.send_keys(f"""Hola {dataframe.loc[i]['Contacto']}
Mi nombre es Luis Contreras y soy KAM de xxxx. En xxxx somos expertos 
en el desarrollo de plataformas de software y en consultorías de innovación y 
transformación digital, nos caracterizamos por nuestro enfoque 
multidisciplinario y profesional, contando con más de 7 años de experiencia 
en el rubro.
Le escribimos dado que al evaluar detenidamente su sitio web 
{dataframe.loc[i]['web']} pudimos identificar las siguientes oportunidades de 
mejora:
-{dataframe.loc[i]['Observaciones']}
Como empresa creemos firmemente que, además de solucionar este tipo de 
problemas, podemos ser el partner tecnológico capaz de llevar su plataforma 
digital a su verdadero potencial. Si esta oportunidad es llamativa para ti y 
te interesa saber un poco más de nuestra empresa, podemos agendar una 
reunión. Si quieres me comunicas tu disponibilidad o eliges un horario 
directamente a través de " https://www.some.com " este enlace
Saludos. 
Luis Contreras.
KAM.
""")
```

Make sure you have space after

`" https://www.some.com "` and `https://www.some.com`  - works

`"https://www.some.com"` this wont't

Comment: im using gmail, this doesnt seem to be working, thanks for helping me.

Comment: @PapillasGustativas in gmail it will be come hyperlink after you send the message , try sending it your self . You will get all urls as hyperlink ,

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means confident, but, it is my understanding that all email clients render HTML. So all you should need to do is include the HTML tag as plain text, which will be rendered by the user's email client when displaying the message. i.e.:

```
cuerpo.send_keys(f"""
...
Como empresa creemos firmemente que, además de solucionar este tipo de 
problemas, podemos ser el partner tecnológico capaz de llevar su plataforma 
digital a su verdadero potencial. Si esta oportunidad es llamativa para ti y 
te interesa saber un poco más de nuestra empresa, podemos agendar una 
reunión. Si quieres me comunicas tu disponibilidad o eliges un horario 
directamente a través de <a href="www.link i want.com">este enlace</a>
""")
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working with gmail, thanks for the response.